# How to pass parameter in constructer (with Hilt as a DI)

Tags: android, dagger-hilt

This is how my class looks like, I need to pass the name parameter when I will inject this class.

```
class Student @Inject constructor( name: String) {
    @Inject
    lateinit var  dept:DepartMent

}
```

Injecting class student

`@Inject lateinit var stud:Student`

Comment: I don't see a `name` parameter anywhere.  Are you missing some of the code you're talking about?

Comment: Sorry for that, now the code is updated

Answer (score 1):

The name you want to pass should be passed by the `Provider`.
Hilt can't create an instance of your object if you haven't told it the way of creating a new object.

```
@Provides
fun provideStudent(): Student {
    return Student("NAME")
}
```

Comment: How to pass a non static string? if we gonna add in the function as a paramter, where will this provideStudent be invoked?